# Response data returns undefined from asp.net web api to vue.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js, webapi

currently I'm fetching data from my api to front-end. I checked and my request body is arriving to server side. But after doing things when it comes to returning the token it always returns undefined data to vue.js:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]User user)
    {
        var result = await _accountRepository.LoginAsync(user.username, user.password);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            return Unauthorized(result);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(result.ToString()); // this works and I can see the token
        return Ok(result);

    }
```

When it comes here:

```
  methods: {
login() {
  fetch("http://localhost:60427/api/account/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password,
    })
  }).then(response => {  
      console.log(response.data); // this is always undefined 
      
    })  
    .catch(e => {  
      console.log(e);  
    });  
},
```

}

Please help I can't see any errors here. I'm confused.

Comment: Try: `console.log(response.text());`

Comment: Hey thanks for that, it helped a bit but now I'm getting pending promise and I can see my token. How can I access that?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your API it's not clear what your response object structure would be. I would look at `console.log(response)` then, after that it's a matter of using.dot.notation.to.get.your.data.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: This isn't how fetch api is used. You'd have response.data in Axios, but fetch isn't axios.

Comment: you need to parse it into json first then read the response

Answer (score 2):

You need to call either [`Response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) or [`Response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) depending on what data you expect. These methods return a Promise that resolves to the data.

E.g. for JSON:

```js
fetch("http://localhost:60427/api/account/login", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password,
  })
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: This method worked but not exactly because the second then method after fetch comes after json() not the first then method.